# How do I declare an Ember template in the class definition using Ember.Handlebars.compile()?

Tags: templates, view, ember.js, ember-router

In the latest ember master build, I'm trying to declare a template similar to this:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Index template in code')
});
```

..and it's not working. Using identical code and referencing a template in HTML using the `templateName` property works fine. Any ideas?

Here's a jsfiddle with the surrounding code and HTML: 
http://jsfiddle.net/TTMMz/3/

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be a bug, if you try to set the defaultTemplate instead of template it will work. You should maybe file an issue.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Index template in code')
});
```

FYI

> For views classes that may have a template later defined (e.g. as
>   the block   portion of a `{{view}}` Handlebars helper call in another
>   template or in   a subclass), you can provide a `defaultTemplate`
>   property set to compiled   template function. If a template is not
>   later provided for the view instance   the `defaultTemplate` value
>   will be used:

```
AView = Ember.View.extend({
     defaultTemplate: Ember.Handlebars.compile('I was the default'),
     template: null,
     templateName: null   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `templateName: 'index'` to `App.IndexView`.  It looks like the router needs/wants a template named `index` and the way you had it in your JSFiddle the router wasn't able to find one.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cteegarden/TTMMz/9/)

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('Index template in code'),
  templateName: 'index'
});
```